# Taking the difference between two dates using pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time

I am trying to take the time difference between two dates using pandas and am having some trouble.

The format the dates are in are as follows:

```
2016/07/06 03:10:39
```

Using pandas.to_datetime I can get these to a datetime64 type but then cannot figure out a way to take the difference of these types.

here is the basis of my code:

```
df2.End = to_datetime(df1.End)
df2.Start = to_datetime(df1.Start)
```

If I print these objects from the Dataframe here is what I get:

```
Series([], Name: End, dtype: datetime64[ns])
Series([], Name: Start, dtype: datetime64[ns])
```

End:

```
0    2016-07-06 04:39:16
1    2016-07-06 04:13:30
2    2016-07-06 03:51:30
```

Start

```
0    2016-07-06 05:01:14
1    2016-07-06 04:39:06
2    2016-07-06 04:13:27
```

I have tried to do the following:

```
df2.difference = df2.End-df2.Start
```

and get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Comment: did you try subtracting them after converting to datetime? it should give you a `timedelta` object

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to do, so we get a better understanding of the situation?

Comment: @EdChum, Yes.  I get this error: TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

Comment: That means your right hand is not a datetime, post your code that gives the error, are you converting or using a datetime for the rhs?

Comment: `df2.Start = pandas.to_datetime(df1.Start)`, `df2.End = pandas.to_datetime(df1.End)`,`df2.difference = df2.End - df2.Start`  both start and end intial string formats are the same and I can get the to_datetime function to work for both, just cannot subtract them for some reason

Comment: Why are the series empty? `Series([], Name: End, dtype: datetime64[ns])`? you'll need to post raw data, code to create your series and the code that leads to this error

Comment: Look at my updated answer. I'ts unclear if you tried `df2.difference = df2.End - df2.Start` as in your comment or `df2.difference = df2.End - df1.Start` as in your post

Comment: @OhadEytan, yes that was a typo.  Sorry.

Comment: what you get for `type(df2.Start)` and `type(df2.End)`? what  about `type(df1.Start)` and `type(df1.End)`?

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the fact that I am slicing the data from another dataframe (from df0 to df1).  I can perform the same operation on the original dataframe and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> x = pandas.to_datetime("2016/07/06 03:10:39")
>>> y = pandas.to_datetime("2016/07/06 03:11:21")
>>> y-x
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:42')
```

Post your code if you still can't figure what your problem.

Comment: the OP wants to create a series equal to y-x; your answer works for specific datetimes